# Find the values of x which makes $f'(x)=-18$ , if $ f(x) = (-9x-4)^2 $??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

While solving this problem, I reach the point at which I should take the square root of $1$. Does the square root equal $1$ or $-1$, and hence $x$ will have two values; or does the square root of $1$ equal only $1$, and hence $x$ will have only one value?

Comment: How, you have $-18 (-4 - 9 x) = -18$?

Comment: $f$ is a second degree polynomial, so $f'$ is a first-degree polynomial, and therefore there should be a unique solution and no choice involved.

Comment: Can you show your calculation?  As written, there shouldn't be a square root in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=(-9x-4)^2=(9x+4)^2$$
$$f'(x)=18(9x+4)$$
We have $$f'(x)=-18$$
Thus
$$18(9x+4)=-18$$
$$9x+4=-1$$
$$x=-5/9$$